# Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil() prevents SnackBar from displaying

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having issues with displaying a `SnackBar` in my app.

My app requires the user to register. Below is just a shortened version of my registration functionality:

**Registration.dart:**

```
void loginPage()
  {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/login",
      arguments: <String, bool>{
        "regSuccess" : true
      });

    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
        body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child:
            Center(
              child:
                Column(
                  child:
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child:
                        Text("Register"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if(_formKey.currentState.validate())
                        {
                          loginPage();
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

When the user clicks the register button they will be redirected to the **Login** page and all previous routes will be removed using `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);`. Data is also sent back to the **Registration** page with the `Navigator.pushNamed` function.

Below is the shortened functionality of the **Login** page:

**Login.dart**

```
void showRegSnackbar()
{
  scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text(
      "Registration Successful!",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
    ),
  ));
}

Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    final Map arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;

    if (arguments != null)
    {
      if(arguments['regSuccess'] == true)
      {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => showRegSnackbar());

        print(arguments['regSuccess']);
      }
    }
}
```

The login page will then display a `SnackBar`, notifying the user that they have successfully registered themselves. However, calling `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()` from the **Login** prevents the `SnackBar` from showing.

How can I display a `SnackBar` after calling the `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use flushbar instead of snackbar
it is more costomizeable
Flushbar doesn't need a scaffold ancestor to work but
Snackbar does,
also Flushbar doesn't is not very heavy as snackbar and **also it solves your current problem.**
you can install it and use it instead of snackbar

[Flushbar Plugin here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flushbar)